# appending and removing an image on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending which is positioned correctly when a li is clicked.  My code works nicely although it keeps adding images to the page because i am not removing them when the li is toggled.  Any ideas?

```
$("#offering li").click(function() {                             
            $(this).find("ul").animate({height: "toggle"}, 500);
            $(this).append('<img width="286" height="15" class="offeringselected" alt="Selected" src="images/bg-offering-li-selected.png">');
            $(this).toggleClass('current');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `.toggle()` event method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), passing it two functions which will be alternated on clicks.

```
$("#offering li").toggle(function() {                             
        $(this).find("ul").animate({height: "toggle"}, 500);
        $(this).addClass('current')
               .append('<img width="286" height="15" class="offeringselected" alt="Selected" src="images/bg-offering-li-selected.png">');
},function() {                             
        $(this).removeClass('current')
               .children('img.offeringselected').remove();
});
```

Or perhaps it would be better to put the image in the page coming from the server, then just show and hide it.

To do this, you could use [the *other* version of `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) that performs a show/hide.

```
$("#offering li").click(function() {                             
        $(this).find("ul").animate({height: "toggle"}, 500);
        $(this).toggleClass('current')
               .children('img.offeringselected').toggle(); // show/hide the img
});
```

Hardcode the image into the `<li>`, and give it an initial `display:none` in CSS.